# Web application reacts differently to Windows reserved names like CON, AUX, NUL

Tags: web-application, windows, file-system

Several web applications I tested have the behavior that reserved Windows filenames such as AUX, CON, NUL, PRN, COM1, LPT1 have different behavior than other pages. For example, `http://example.com/foo` will give a 404, where `http://example.com/aux` will give an 500 error.

What causes this behavior? Does this indicate a security problem?

Comment: I've seen this quite a lot, but haven't managed to deduce anything beyond "it's running IIS" from it. However, it would be really useful if someone did know more.

Comment: I believe more information about the system is required to provide a meaningful answer, for example are you really running IIS? which version? Still, from the looks of it I would treat it as a configuration "caveat" and not as a security concern, perhaps SuperUser is a better place for this unless you're wondering about fingerprinting the OS (in which case I would reword the question)

Answer (score 2):

By default on an IIS server the path of a URL is validated by using the same rules that determine whether a Windows file system path is valid. So this is the reason why `http://example.com/aux` can give an 500 (aux is an invalid directory name) but `http://example.com/foo` a 404 (foo is ok). This behavior can be disabled by setting
`relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping = true` in web.config.

Apart from a possible small information disclosure that you are running an IIS server there is no security problem.